# windows vim ":py import socket" returns "load dll failed: method not found"

Tags: python, sockets, winapi, vim

I have a vim74 portable (win32):

```
 VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 10 2013 14:38:33)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Compiled by mool@tororo
Big version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic             +ex_extra           +mouseshape         +syntax
+autocmd            +extra_search       +multi_byte_ime/dyn +tag_binary
+balloon_eval       +farsi              +multi_lang         +tag_old_static
+browse             +file_in_path       -mzscheme           -tag_any_white
++builtin_terms     +find_in_path       +netbeans_intg      +tcl/dyn
+byte_offset        +float              +ole                -tgetent
+cindent            +folding            +path_extra         -termresponse
+clientserver       -footer             +perl/dyn           +textobjects
+clipboard          +gettext/dyn        +persistent_undo    +title
+cmdline_compl      -hangul_input       -postscript         +toolbar
+cmdline_hist       +iconv/dyn          +printer            +user_commands
+cmdline_info       +insert_expand      -profile            +vertsplit
+comments           +jumplist           +python/dyn         +virtualedit
+conceal            +keymap             +python3/dyn        +visual
+cryptv             +langmap            +quickfix           +visualextra
+cscope             +libcall            +reltime            +viminfo
+cursorbind         +linebreak          +rightleft          +vreplace
+cursorshape        +lispindent         +ruby/dyn           +wildignore
+dialog_con_gui     +listcmds           +scrollbind         +wildmenu
+diff               +localmap           +signs              +windows
+digraphs           -lua                +smartindent        +writebackup
-dnd                +menu               -sniff              -xfontset
-ebcdic             +mksession          +startuptime        -xim
+emacs_tags         +modify_fname       +statusline         -xterm_save
+eval               +mouse              -sun_workshop       +xpm_w32
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc"
3rd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG   
-DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400  /Fo.\ObjGOLYHTRi386/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT 
-DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_GUI_W32 -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT 
-DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl85.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.5\" -DFEAT_PYTHON 
-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 
-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python32.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl514.dll\" 
-DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=19 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby192.dll\" -DFEAT_BIG 
/Fd.\ObjGOLYHTRi386/ /Zi
Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib
```

Python 2.7.9 was installed and %path% contained a path to the python27.dll.

Command ":py print 2+2" returns 4 but ":py import socket" returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module> 
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: method not found
```

Command ":!python -c "import socket" " works without any errors.

What's wrong? How I can fix this error?
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by copying python's files (python27.dll, python.exe, pythonw.exe) to the vim app folder (there are vim.exe, gvim.exe, diff.exe and other files).

Good luck and do not forget to remove the msvcrt90.dll from the python folder or to delete a path to the python folder from the %path% variable ;)